# Loading Flash Content while opening an Image link

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, http

The following image is hosted at puu.sh (http://puu.sh/k0Hki.jpg), apparently it loads a swf with a .jpg extension in the url.

The following is what chrome/firefox shows as the source (while using developer tools)

[Firefox Developer Tools Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V53me.png)

How could we replicate it on a different server(preferably nginx)

Comment: What do you mean by 'replicate'? A proxy?

Comment: I would like to upload it to my personal server the similar way.

Comment: Well it's just a static file being served. What is your specific question?

Comment: I am not sure how to exactly do it. Serving SWF with JPG extension.